# Use \unbkt \ovbkt with the same notes MusiXTeX

Tags: musixtex

I need to write this image with MusiXTeX code:

[image]

My problem is to combine `\unbkt` `\ovbkt` commands with the same notes. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}[12]

\usepackage{musixtex}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \nobarnumbers
    \startextract
    \NOTEs
        \ovbkt n34 \unbkt n11 \wh{e h}
        \ccharnote{12}{$8^{a}$}\wh{i l}
    \en
    \endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What exactly has been modified today?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't changed the beginning note (both times "n"). I changed your code in various ways. This is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}[12]

\usepackage{musixtex}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \nobarnumbers
    \startextract
    \NOTEs
        \unbkt b11\wh{e h}\bsk\ovbkt n24\sk
        \ccharnote{12}{$8^{a}$}\wh{i l}
    \en
    \endextract
    
      \startextract
    \NOTEs
        \unbkt b11\wh e\ovbkt n24\wh h
        \ccharnote{12}{$8^{a}$}\wh{i l}
    \en
    \endextract
    
      \startextract
    \NOTEs
        \unbkt b11\ovbkt n34\wh{e h}
        \ccharnote{12}{$8^{a}$}\wh{i l}
    \en
    \endextract


\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image: unbkt and ovbkt]